# How can I lessen acidental clicks with viewPager?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

On my android app I have a viewPager and I have it so that when a user clicks on an image they can share it. When using the viewPager it is resulting in way to many accidental clicks and causing users to get irritated with the share dialog continuously popping up.

So I was wondering what the best way to stop the accidental clicks is?

I have tried creating a menu option to share the image but it didn't work out because of the way I have the classes set up.

Comment: Have you thought about or tried changing it to a long press? You could set the duration of the touch to however long you like

Comment: @Asok I can't believe I didn't think of that. Thanks!